# Print the words of the string and their length along the same time

Tags: python, compiler-errors, string-length

Hoping you all to be fit and fine....

I have been trying since a while to get the result of one of the codes that I have written....but unable to get the desired result...Would be more than happy if you could help me out...☺☺

I have got a string and I need to print the words of the string and their length along the same time with a colon in between.....This is my
[code](https://code.sololearn.com/cY7Ge74w7f7f)
and This is the result I am in need:

[This:4 is: 2 pretty: 6]

pretty

But an error is popping up while I am trying to print the first line of the result....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sent = "Hello Word!"

print([f"{word}:{len(word)}" for word in sent.split()])
```

Comment: you literally copied my solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sentence = 'This is pretty'
result = [f'{w}:{len(w)}' for w in sentence.split()]
```

This is the result:

```
>>> result
['This:4', 'is:2', 'pretty:6']
```

Comment: hey Ricardo...Thanks a bunch for helping me out...I have altered my code as you mentioned....this is the code <https://code.sololearn.com/cY7Ge74w7f7f/#py> and this is the result I am getting....                                                                                                       
['This:4', 'is:2', 'pretty:6']
pretty
Is there a way that I can get the result something of this sort...                                     
['This':4, 'is':2, 'pretty':6]
pretty @Ricardo Bucco

Answer (score 0):

```
word_count=[]
for w in words:
    c = w + ":" + str(len(w)) 
    word_count.append(c)

print(word_count)
```

Output:

```
['This:4', 'is:2', 'pretty:6']
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like this?

```
sent = "This is pretty"
words = sent.split(" ")
print([word + ":"+str(len(word)) for word in words])
#print(list(word,":",len(word)))

length = [len(word) for word in words]
maximum=max(length)
text_index=length.index(maximum)
longest_word=words[text_index]
print(longest_word )
```

Output:

```
['This:4', 'is:2', 'pretty:6']
pretty
```